# What is the proper way of using/referencing the *.py file generated form Qt Designer?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

I'm new to Python. I have a large GUI I created in Qt Designer. I specifically want to use the *.py file it generates instead of using loadUi() because my program has a lot of steps that tends to make it slow, so I want to save as much time as possible.

The GUI needs to be changed/updated on a semi-regular basis (every few weeks, give or take), so ideally I would like the Qt Designer *.py file to be a standalone file that I can just export every time I make a change. Then I can load that class into a different class in main.py and add in all the "button clicked" code and other follow-on functions. That way I never have to edit the Qt *.py file manually.

Is this the proper way of dealing with a Qt designer file? If so, how do I do this???

Here is what I have so far that I'm pretty sure is wrong:

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from UI_MainWindow_Qt import Ui_MainWindow

#Main GUI
class Figure_Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    #create the figure with buttons and everything
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        #if button gets clicked, call method1()

    def method1(self):
        #do some stuff'
```

**UI_MainWindow_Qt**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        #setup the rest of the GUI's buttons and such
```

This is what I had initially, but the Figure_Main class is a few thousand lines of code and I feel like it muddies up the file.

**main.py**

```
#Main GUI
class Figure_Main(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        #setup the rest of the GUI's buttons and such (from Qt Designer)
        #if buttons get clicked, call method1() (manually added)

    def method1(self):
        #do some stuff

if __name__ == "__main__":

    #display main GUI window
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv) 
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow() 
    ui = Figure_Main() 
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow) 
    MainWindow.show()
```

Comment: That's one of the most common ways to load the ui (known as the "multiple inheritance approach" in the [PyQt5 Docs](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#using-the-generated-code)). Certainly you should always avoid editing the output generated by pyuic.

Comment: @ekhumoro Ah, putting a name to it is making it much easier to google, thank you! So it looks like what I have is mostly working correctly, then. But how do I show the GUI? I used to have MainWindow.show() in my if __name__ == "__main__" script, but now I don't have "MainWindow" and I don't know how to get it visible.

Comment: Add app.exec_() after show

Comment: @AmandaBeatty Create an instance of your main-window subclass, then show it and start the event-loop: `app = QApplication(sys.argv); window = Figure_Main(); window.show(); sys.exit(app.exec_())`. One other minor improvement would be to use `super().__init__()` instead of explicitly calling the base-class (there's no need to pass `self` when using that approach).